# How to Update State in map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in a state, update all values under map Function

```
const [docUrls, setDocUrls] = useState({ imageUrl: "",  panUrl: "", statementUrl: "" })

data.map(item=>
 item.type==='image' ?
setDocUrls({ ...docUrls, imageUrl:item.url })

:item.type==='panUrl' ?
setDocUrls({ ...docUrls, panUrl:item.url  })

:item.type==='statement' ?
setDocUrls({ ...docUrls, statementUrl: item.url})

)
```

Comment: so are facing any issue in this?

Comment: Yes its not updating all, its updating one

Comment: If you have two items one after the other and each has a `type` `image` the second one will overwrite the information that the first one added to the `imageUrl`. Is that what's meant to happen? If you could add some example input data, and your expected output to your question that would help understand your use-case.

Comment: I would suggest you store that into an object and finally update your state. Updating the state inside the map will cause multiple renderings(as the state is updating) and it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.forEach(item=>
 item.type==='image' ? docUrls.imageUrl = item.url

:item.type==='panUrl' ?docUrls.panUrl = item.url

:item.type==='statement' ? docUrls.statementUrl = item.url

)
setDocUrls(docUrls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```js
const [docUrls, setDocUrls] = useState({ imageUrl: "",  panUrl: "", statementUrl: "" })
const keyMap = {
    image: 'imageUrl',
    panUrl: 'panUrl',
    statement: 'statementUrl',
}

const handleUpdateState = (key, value) => {
    setDocUrls((old) => ({ ...old, [key]: value }));
};

data.forEach(item=>{
    handleUpdateState(keyMap[item.type], item.url)
})
```

Method 2

```js
const [docUrls, setDocUrls] = useState({ imageUrl: '', panUrl: '', statementUrl: '' });
const keyMap = {
    image: 'imageUrl',
    panUrl: 'panUrl',
    statement: 'statementUrl',
};

const handleUpdateState = () => {
    const result = {};
    data.forEach((i) => {
        result[keyMap[i.type]] = i.url;
    });
    setDocUrls(old => ({...old, ...result}));
};
```